# IE7 Image loaded from class bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Issues with IE7, and images...
My CSS

```
.dot-preview {
    background: url("../images/bola02.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 13px;
}

.navi-active .dot-preview {
    background: url("../images/bola01.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 13px;
}
```

My HTML

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navi"><span class="navbar-img"><img class="dot-preview"></span></a></li>
  <li> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="navi-active"><span class="navbar-img"><img class="dot-preview"></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The website:
http://di20studios.com/argento/

And the problem are at the left, above slideshow.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: The problem is, I expect this: http://di20studios.com/argento/modules/mod_fpss/tmpl/Custom/images/bola02.png and get a square...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as far as i understand, your problem exists in IE7 and less only. If yes, then the answer is easy: IE7 and less don't support transparent images. Try this one:
http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Good luck